# performSelector with more than 2 objects

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to call [anObject performSelector]; with more than 2 objects?  I know you can use an array to pass multiple arguments, but I was wondering if there was a lower level way to call a function I already have defined with more that 2 arguments without using a helper function with an nsarray of arguments.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Either (1) Use an [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or (2) directly use `objc_msgSend`.

```
objc_msgSend(target, @selector(action:::), arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

(Note: make sure all arguments are `id`'s, otherwise the arguments might not be sent correctly.)

Comment: When using objc_msgSend, you'll need to #import <objc/message.h> as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896510/how-to-import-nsobjcruntime-h-to-use-objc-msgsend

Comment: that last note you made about making sure all args are of type id's.. can you explain further? or provide some resource please? i cant find any.

Answer (score 14):

You can extend the `NSObject` class like this:

```
- (id) performSelector: (SEL) selector withObject: (id) p1
       withObject: (id) p2 withObject: (id) p3
{
    NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!sig)
        return nil;

    NSInvocation* invo = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
    [invo setTarget:self];
    [invo setSelector:selector];
    [invo setArgument:&p1 atIndex:2];
    [invo setArgument:&p2 atIndex:3];
    [invo setArgument:&p3 atIndex:4];
    [invo invoke];
    if (sig.methodReturnLength) {
        id anObject;
        [invo getReturnValue:&anObject];
        return anObject;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

(See [NSObjectAdditions](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/NSObjectAdditions.m) from the Three20 project.) Then you could even extend the above method to use [varargs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2005/qa1405.html) and nil-terminated array of arguments, but that’s overkill.

Answer (score 0):

An additional option, when you require to send multiple objects with `performSelector` is (if it's easy enough to do) to amend the method you wish to call to take an `NSDictionary` object instead of multiple parameters, as you'll be able to send as many as you like within the dictionary.

For example

I had a method similar to this which had 3 arguments and I needed to call it from performSelector -

```
-(void)getAllDetailsForObjectId:(NSString*)objId segment:(Segment*)segment inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{
```

I changed this method to make use of a dictionary to store the arguments

```
-(void)getAllDetailsForObject:(NSDictionary*)details{
```

therefore I was able to call the method easily

```
[self performSelector:@selector(getAllDetailsForObject:) withObject:@{Your info stored within a dictionary}];
```

Thought I'd be as well sharing this as an alternative option as it works for me.

Cheers