# How to #import <NSObjCRuntime.h> to use objc_msgSend

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to import runtime's header to use objc_msgSend but I'm getting:

```
error: NSObjCRuntime.h: No such file or directory
```

Should I add something to the header search path?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to include `<objc/message.h>` (you'll find the related headers in `/usr/include/objc`) and link to the `objc` (`/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib`) library.

Comment: It worked! Can you share where did you find that? I've browsed the apple docs, google code search, and nothing !

Answer (score 38):

`#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>` does work

but you probably need

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

[like this Apple example does](http://www.codecollector.net/view/2F26056B-EC5A-4FC3-8886-9C7C39DFF07F)

upd: since iOS 7 `#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>` replaced to `#import <objc/NSObjCRuntime.h>` but i recommend to use `#import <objc/runtime.h>` anyway

Comment: The method `objc_msgSend` is declared in `<objc/message.h>`, not in `<objc/runtime.h>`. So you will get a warning for implicitly declaring library function.

Answer (score 2):

When using Xcode 6 and later, you will get an error after `#include<objc/message.h>`. It can be resolved like this

```
#include <objc/message.h>
void foo(void *object) {
  typedef void (*send_type)(id, SEL, int);
  send_type func = (send_type)objc_msgSend;
  func(object, sel_getUid("foo:"), 5);
}
```

http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/417xx2zsyyp8zcs/417/417_whats_new_in_llvm.pdf