# Use performSelector with three or more arguments?

Tags: objective-c, selector, performselector

The various `performSelector:...` methods can handle a maximum of two arguments passed to the specified selector. What can I do if I need to pass three or more arguments?

Comment: Yeah, if you have control over the callee side the simplest approach is to throw the parms into an NSDictionary.  And even if you don't "own" the callee you can often make a "glue" routine in your own class to call it (assuming you're creating the selector, vs having it handed to you).  Otherwise the NSInvocation approach is what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [performSelector with more than 2 objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346733/performselector-with-more-than-2-objects)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use NSInvocation class for that. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies) for more details on using them.

Answer (score 3):

I dislike the `NSInvocation` way, it needs too much code.

If you’d like perform the selector immediately, here is an simple and clean way:

```
// Assume we have these variables
id target, SEL aSelector, id parameter1, id parameter2;

// Get the method IMP, method is a function pointer here.
id (*method)(id, SEL, id, id) = (void *)[vc methodForSelector:aSelector];

// IMP is just a C function, so we can call it directly.
id returnValue = method(vc, aSelector, parameter1, parameter2);
```