# performSelectorInBackground with more that 2 parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am trying to execute a performSelectorInBackground with an object and a block.
I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346733/performselector-with-more-than-2-objects) answer but it wasn't helpful for my case. The reason it wasn't helpful it's because the answer there is for passing 2 parameters as objects but in my case is passing an object and a callback.

This is my code:

```
static ACallBack aCallback;
- (void)doSometginh:(Book*)aBook callback:(ClassCallback)aCallback
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doVeryLongTask1:callback:) withObject:aPerson withObject:aCallback];
}
```

The code is wrong because it wont accept the second parameter.
Any ideas how to parse the block as second parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [performSelector with more than 2 objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346733/performselector-with-more-than-2-objects)

Comment: @kirander I don't know if you notice that I mention this question. My problem is different.

Comment: The same problem. Did you try to nest 2 objects in one (NSDictionary, Struct, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `Grand Central Dispatch`?
You could do something like:

```
static TestClassCallback savedCallback;
- (void)doSometginh:(Book*)aBook callback:(ClassCallback)aCallback {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        [self doVeryLongTask1:aPerson callback:aCallback];
    });
}
```

You can perform the callback in the main thread with this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    callback();
});
```

**EDIT:**
Those calls can be nested.
For example if you want to have Task1 and Task2 that run in the background and you want to update something on the mainthread between them:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    // Task 1
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // Update on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            // Task 2
        });
    });
});
```

Add another call of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){` after `// Task 2` to add a final callback on the mainthread.

Comment: Because I need to update the UI from the main thread once a while so I am using performSelectorOnMainThreas!

Comment: +1 Never use `performSelectorInBackground:` or `performSelectorOnMainThread:`. The former is dangerous and can easily lead to thread explosion. The latter is just overly restrictive (particularly in Swift). GCD and `NSOperationQueue` are the correct tools and are the replacement for most of the `performSelector...` methods. As @zoleas notes, you can easily put UI activities on the main queue using GCD or `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Since I am new to MultiThreading, my question is: I have Task1 and Task2 that I would run in background. But I want to update the UI between Task 1 and 2. How to do that with GCD? I know main queue operations on GCD are executed at the end as callback. Am I wrong?